# Is there a way for iPython to generate these kinds of charts given a dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, ipython

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dS3u.jpg)

Please ignore the background image. The foreground chart is what I am interested in showing using pandas or numpy or scipy (or anything in iPython).

I have a dataframe where each row represents temperatures for a single day. 
This is an example of some rows:

```
            100   200   300   400   500   600 ...... 2300
10/3/2013  53*C  57*C  48*C  49*C  54*C  54*C        55*C
10/4/2013  45*C  47*C  48*C  49*C  50*C  52*C        57*C
```

Is there a way to get a chart that represents the changes from hour to hour using the first column as a 'zero'

Answer (score 2):

Something quick and dirty that might get you most of the way there, assuming your data frame is named `df`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(df.T.diff().fillna(0.0).T.drop(0, axis=1).values)
```

Since I can't easily construct a sample version with your exact column labels, there might be slight additional tinkering with getting rid of any index columns that are included in the `diff` and moved with the transposition. But this worked to make a simple heat-map-ish plot for me on a random data example.

Then you can create a matplotlib figure or axis object and specify whatever you want for the x- and y-axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

You could just plot lines one at a time for each row with an offset:

```
nrows, ncols = 12, 30

# make up some fake data:
d = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)
d *= np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(ncols)*4/ncols)
d *= np.exp(-0.5*(np.arange(nrows)-nrows/2)**2/(nrows/4)**2)[:,None]

#this is all you need, if you already have the data:
for i, r in enumerate(d):
    plt.fill_between(np.arange(ncols), r+(nrows-i)/2., lw=2, facecolor='white')
```

[image: Overlapping lines]

You could do it all at once if you don't need the fill color to block the previous line:

```
d += np.arange(nrows)[:, None]
plt.plot(d.T)
```

[image: Not filled]